# Dialogbox doesn't show orginal form

Tags: c#, windows, mobile, dialog, windows-mobile-6.5

I have a Windows Mobile 6.5 App under development. When the user opens the App a dialog box appears with the login form. User logs in and then after 30 seconds (small time in production) when the timer has run out without activity I show the login Dialog box again using events:

```
static private void _TimerTick(object state)
    {
        // the user has been inactive for 30 secs; log him out
        MainForm.timer = null;
        using (LoginForm LoginForm = new LoginForm())
        {

            if (LoginForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
               MainForm.timer = new System.Threading.Timer(_TimerTick, null, 1000 * 30 * 1, Timeout.Infinite);
            }
            else
            {
                Application.Exit();
            }
        } 


    }
```

But once I press login and return with an ok button from the login form the original form does show. Although it is still in the task manager. I have tried:
.TopMost = true; but then I can't assess the windows button in the bar at the bottom of the app and no other apps can run as form in my app is always in front of it.

Comment: I am sorry, but the description is not clear to me. Can you explain in more details? Compact Framework will not dispose a form as long as there are references left to the form. It will also not close applications as long as there are running threads created by the application.

Comment: For some reason when the dialog box closed the program was hidden. It went to the phones last open program or home screen. The program was still in the task manager but not visible until I swithc back to the task. I have had a play around and change some of my code and it doesn't do it now! Strange! Thanks anyways!

Comment: In fact, It was form inheritance that was the issue I think. The dialog box inheritate the same form class as the original form. So that could have been the issue!

Comment: Ok so I am getting the same issue again! So maybe I didn't resolve the issue.

I have an event called: userActivityEvent,

every time somebody clicked a button or does something a timer resets, when that timer runs out a function is called to logout.

The dialog works perfectly, closes and shows original form as expected once a response is received.

But I have a logout button on my main form and I call this same function and the dialogbox shows but once I return with "OK" the original form isn't visible. It is still in the task manager but I have to switch to it manually to make it visible.

Comment: Looks like you need to manage your stack of forms and track and control which form to show/activate when.

Comment: My application is very basic with only 1 form and then a login form which is use as a dialog box. So it's strange. I will do more debugging.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution as this is only for the login and one main form:

LoginForm.cs (with two textboxes and main menu with Login and Exit):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LoginFormTest
{

    public partial class LoginForm : Form
    {
        public LoginForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void doShow(bool bShow)
        {
            if(bShow)
                Invoke(new Action(() => this.Show()));
            else
                Invoke(new Action(() => this.Hide()));
        }

        public void doClose()
        {
            Invoke(new Action(() => this.Close()));
        }

        private void mnuLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MainForm mainForm = new MainForm();
            mainForm.Show();
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("mainForm started");
        }

    }
}
```

Nothing special there.
The MainForm has code that will close the form if no activity:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using System.Threading;

namespace LoginFormTest
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        int countDown = 3;  //number of seconds for timeout

        System.Threading.Timer timer;
        object lockCounter = new object(); //to sync access to counter var

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //start a independent timer after 1000ms and with a 1000ms interval
            timer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(this.timerCallback), null, 1000, 1000);
        }

        private void mnuExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            doClose();
        }

        private void mnuLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            doClose();
        }

        private void doClose()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("mainForm closing");
            try
            {
                timer.Dispose(); //else timer thread will continue running!
                Invoke(new Action(() => this.Close()));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Exception in doClose(): " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void MainForm_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            resetTimeout();
        }

        private void MainForm_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            resetTimeout();
        }

        private void MainForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            resetTimeout();
        }

        public void resetTimeout()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("resetTimeout()");
            lock(lockCounter)
                countDown = 3;
        }

        public void timerCallback(object stateInfo)
        {
            lock (lockCounter)
                countDown--;
            if (countDown == 0)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("timeout->doClose()");
                doClose();
            }
        }

        private void MainForm_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("mainForm CLOSED");
        }

    }
}
```

Specials:

- a lock object to sync access to the counter var
- a threading timer that runs independent of the message pump
- a delegate to by called from the TimerCallback function